# Aggregate with Default Value in Parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

Why is it not possible to supply a default value that is defined in the parameter list for a struct? That is, why does this work

```
struct C {int i;};
C cc = {0};

foo(C c=cc) {}
```

but not

```
foo(C c={0}) {}
```

Note, I've noticed that the same holds true for arrays.

Comment: except for the non-existant return value of `foo`, both compiles on my gcc.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Have you verified that your compiler is standard conforming?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/oXExo9. I'm using GCC 4.7 with c++0x flag.

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/8dVg3I) compiles with `g++ -pedantic -std=c++11` without error. My gcc version is `4.7.2`. Of course, that doesn't necessary mean that it is conforming.

Comment: So this could be a compiler error?

Comment: Got it working with my compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems this is a compiler problem with the older GCC.